# Outlook VBA 2013 : Automating Saving of Attachments

Tags: vba, email-attachments, outlook-2010

I'm using the following code to save email photo's to a specific folder :

```
Private Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
saveFolder = "C:\Temp\"

For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
If objAtt.FileName <> "image001.gif" Then
    objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & itm.Subject & ".JPG"
End If

Set objAtt = Nothing
Next
End Sub
```

However I can't get it to actually work. I've tried saving it in ThisOutlookSession and as a module attached to a rule but nothing is being saved.

I'm also looking to create another script to save the comments of the email to a text file where the specific text would be written in [COMMENT] tags in the body. Is this possible ?

Comment: How are you calling this sub?

Comment: I think that's the problem ! I've tried creating a rule where it fires the script on incoming messages to the specified account but nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code I got to work :

```
Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment

Dim dateFormat
dateFormat = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd")

'Message subject should be the meter serial number i.e.K11TB00864
Dim subject
subject = Trim(itm.subject)

Dim saveFolder As String
saveFolder = "C:\Temp\Photo"

For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
If objAtt.FileName <> "image001.gif" Then
objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & itm.subject & " " & dateFormat & ".jpg"
End If

Set objAtt = Nothing
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an extra "\" in the path.

Try objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & itm.Subject & ".JPG"

or saveFolder = "C:\Temp"

Comment: Thank you for that I hadn't spotted it ! I've now got it running from a rule and it works perfectly !